# jQuery slideUp / slideDown work only for mobile / resizing issue

Tags: jquery, window-resize

I am trying do achieve slideUp/slideDown function of a div only on mobile/tablet not desktop. All working good until I resize the screen from mobile/tablet to desktop and vice versa - then function is sliding up/down / is glitchy when it should not be.

```
categoryAccordionSidebar();

var resizeTimer;

$(window).on('resize', function(e) {
    clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
    resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        categoryAccordionSidebar();
    }, 300);
});

function categoryAccordionSidebar() {       
    if(window.innerWidth <= 993) {            
        $(".category-title").click(function() {
            if($(".category-title span").hasClass("categories-arrow-down")) {
                $(".category-title span").addClass("categories-arrow-up").removeClass("categories-arrow-down");
                $(".category-sidebar ul").slideDown();
            } else {
                $(".category-title span").addClass("categories-arrow-down").removeClass("categories-arrow-up");
                $(".category-sidebar ul").slideUp();
            }        
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I made accordion in CSS3 with this solution with @media queries handling the expected breakpoint displays. http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/accordions/

jQuery code

```
$(".category-sidebar .category-title").click(function () {        
    $(".category-sidebar ul").toggleClass("open");
    $(".category-sidebar .category-title .categories-arrow").toggleClass("categories-arrow-rotate");      
});
```